# C++ Application access violation - initalize COM with CoInitializeEx

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I need to run some queries on the WMI using C++, to do that one must call CoInitializeEx.

In 32bit mode it runs fine, and i can initialize COM and also query the wmi.
But if i switch to 64bit (Debug or Release doesn't make a difference) i get an AccessViolation, but only if i debug the application(debugger is attached).

Reproduction of the issue:
Create a new C++ Windows Application (no CLR) with Visual Studio(2019/17 was used). Replace the code with the example code below and start the application in debug mode (Win32/x86) by hitting run in Visual Studio, it should all work fine.
Now switch to x64 and hit run again. Now you should get an AccessViolation exception.

I think the issue has to do something with the debugger. This code will be located in a separate DLL later, that will be used in different C# and C++ applications, since those applications are fairly big we need to be able to debug them.

Can somebody help me solve the issue?

If i open the Application directly from the command line or from the explorer it runs fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{    
    PVOID ThreadLocalStoragePointer = (PVOID)__readgsqword(0x58); //added because of request in comments
    CoInitialize(0);
}
```

ThreadLocalStoragePointer = 0x000000ae2c859058;

Output window (cleared before CoInitialize(0) call):

```
 'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tmumh\20019\AddOn\8.0.0.1056\TmUmEvt64.dll'. 
    'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE24D53D3A (shlwapi.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Stacktrace:

```
shlwapi.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,class Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create(void)
shlwapi.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,class Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::StaticInitialize(void)
shlwapi.dll!`dynamic initializer for 'Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::isInitialized''()
msvcrt.dll!_initterm()
shlwapi.dll!_CRT_INIT()
shlwapi.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup()
ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine()
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeNode()
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()
ntdll.dll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution()
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDllInternal()
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll()
ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll()
00000134cfac0124()
```

Modules:
[image: Modules]

00000134cfac0124() i don't know where this instruction is lcoated, but it is different everytime i restart the programm. In the assembly there are only about 20 instructions before it and before those there are instructions with ?? ?? so i would guess it's the entry point of the program?

Dissasmbly of first entry in callstack (see last instruction)

```
000002504337004C  ?? ?? 
000002504337004D  ?? ?? 
000002504337004E  ?? ?? 
000002504337004F  ?? ?? 
0000025043370050  ?? ?? 
0000025043370051  ?? ?? 
0000025043370052  ?? ?? 
0000025043370053  and         al,30h  
0000025043370056  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
000002504337005B  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+408h]  
0000025043370062  mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rax  
0000025043370067  lea         rax,[rsp+48h]  
000002504337006C  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax  
0000025043370071  mov         r9d,20h  
0000025043370077  lea         r8,[rsp+40h]  
000002504337007C  lea         rdx,[rsp+30h]  
0000025043370081  mov         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
0000025043370088  call        qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
000002504337008C  mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],0  
0000025043370094  jmp         00000250433700A1  
0000025043370096  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+60h]  
000002504337009A  add         eax,1  
000002504337009D  mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],eax  
00000250433700A1  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
00000250433700A6  mov         eax,dword ptr [rax+734h]  
00000250433700AC  cmp         dword ptr [rsp+60h],eax  
00000250433700B0  jae         0000025043370129  
00000250433700B2  mov         qword ptr [rsp+78h],0  
00000250433700BB  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+60h]  
00000250433700BF  imul        rcx,rcx,104h  
00000250433700C6  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
00000250433700CB  movzx       eax,word ptr [rax+rcx+528h]  
00000250433700D3  mov         word ptr [rsp+68h],ax  
00000250433700D8  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+60h]  
00000250433700DC  imul        rcx,rcx,104h  
00000250433700E3  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
00000250433700E8  movzx       eax,word ptr [rax+rcx+528h]  
00000250433700F0  mov         word ptr [rsp+6Ah],ax  
00000250433700F5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+60h]  
00000250433700F9  imul        rcx,rcx,104h  
0000025043370100  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
0000025043370105  lea         rax,[rax+rcx+428h]  
000002504337010D  mov         qword ptr [rsp+70h],rax  
0000025043370112  lea         r9,[rsp+78h]  
0000025043370117  lea         r8,[rsp+68h]  
000002504337011C  xor         edx,edx  
000002504337011E  xor         ecx,ecx  
0000025043370120  call        qword ptr [rsp+58h]  
**0000025043370124  jmp         0000025043370096**
```

Exception is thrown at CoInitialize(NULL)
Exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE24D53D3A (shlwapi.dll) 
in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 
0x0000000000000000.
```

The code is directly called in the main method from the application, not from any dll, although it is the same when called from a dll

Disassembly (Instruction that throws exception: 00007FFE24D53D3A with rax and rcx beeing 0)

```
Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create:
00007FFE24D53D20  push        rbx  
00007FFE24D53D22  sub         rsp,20h  
00007FFE24D53D26  mov         rax,qword ptr gs:[58h]  
00007FFE24D53D2F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [_tls_index (07FFE24D9A9C8h)]  
00007FFE24D53D35  mov         edx,4  
00007FFE24D53D3A  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rax+rcx*8]  
00007FFE24D53D3E  mov         eax,dword ptr [rdx+rcx]  
00007FFE24D53D41  cmp         dword ptr [TSS0<`template-parameter-2',Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::eate,Microsoft::WRL::Details::$00::faultModule,void,int, ?? &> (07FFE24D9ACF0h)],eax  
00007FFE24D53D47  jle         Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create+7Bh (07FFE24D53D9Bh)  
00007FFE24D53D49  lea         rcx,[TSS0<`template-parameter-2',Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::eate,Microsoft::WRL::Details::$00::faultModule,void,int, ?? &> (07FFE24D9ACF0h)]  
00007FFE24D53D50  call        _Init_thread_header (07FFE24D5A6B8h)  
00007FFE24D53D55  cmp         dword ptr [TSS0<`template-parameter-2',Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::eate,Microsoft::WRL::Details::$00::faultModule,void,int, ?? &> (07FFE24D9ACF0h)],0FFFFFFFFh  
00007FFE24D53D5C  jne         Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create+7Bh (07FFE24D53D9Bh)  
00007FFE24D53D5E  lea         rax,[Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1>::`vftable' (07FFE24D7A010h)]  
00007FFE24D53D65  lea         rbx,[`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create'::`2'::moduleSingleton (07FFE24D9ACF8h)]  
00007FFE24D53D6C  mov         qword ptr [`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create'::`2'::moduleSingleton (07FFE24D9ACF8h)],rax  
00007FFE24D53D73  lea         rcx,[`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'moduleSingleton'' (07FFE24D5C3A0h)]  
00007FFE24D53D7A  mov         qword ptr [Microsoft::WRL::Details::ModuleBase::module_ (07FFE24D9AB18h)],rbx  
00007FFE24D53D81  call        atexit (07FFE24D5A4ACh)  
00007FFE24D53D86  lea         rcx,[TSS0<`template-parameter-2',Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::eate,Microsoft::WRL::Details::$00::faultModule,void,int, ?? &> (07FFE24D9ACF0h)]  
00007FFE24D53D8D  call        _Init_thread_footer (07FFE24D5A658h)  
00007FFE24D53D92  mov         rax,rbx  
00007FFE24D53D95  add         rsp,20h  
00007FFE24D53D99  pop         rbx  
00007FFE24D53D9A  ret  
00007FFE24D53D9B  lea         rax,[`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create'::`2'::moduleSingleton (07FFE24D9ACF8h)]  
00007FFE24D53DA2  jmp         Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create+75h (07FFE24D53D95h)  
00007FFE24D53DA4  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DA5  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DA6  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DA7  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DA8  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DA9  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAA  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAB  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAC  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAD  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAE  int         3  
00007FFE24D53DAF  int         3
```

Comment: Nobody is going to get a repro from this snippet.  Diagnosing AVE requires a stack trace with debugging symbols enabled, we can't see it.  But in general, if this *exact* code fails with AVE then you can't do anything but reinstall VS.

Comment: Followed your reproduction steps and I cannot reproduce the issue. It prints the expected result when started from within Visual Studio in Debug x64 mode.

Comment: Unless the AV is actually reaching your code at runtime (and it doesn't sound like it is), then don't worry about it, it is an internal error that is already being handled so just tell the debugger to ignore it and move on with your debugging efforts.

Comment: I will provide a stack trace tomorrow in the morning, we could reproduce the issue on two PCs today one with vs 2017 and the other with vs 2019.

Comment: It works fine in Debug/Release x64/x86 mode in Windows10, vs2017.

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Comment: at first - from which line your code was exception - from `CoInitialize(NULL)` ? `134cfac0124`what is address - in which module this address located ? i be say something(dll ?) loaded in your process inside `CoInitialize(0)` call and this code call `LdrLoadDll` for `shlwapi.dll`. need more debug info. also access violation - post screenshot say - where exactly inside `Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create` - this is small function.

Comment: @RbMm i added the needed information

Comment: @Niall the stacktrace is what i get by looking at the callstack in Visual Studio in exactly this code sample

Comment: ok. understand. now all attention for *0134cfac0124* address (of course it can be different every time) - look dll list loaded to process - are it belong to some dll ? or this is not in any dll ? then - before you execute line `CoInitialize(0)` clear all in VS output window (*Clear All*) button - and then - what new lines (say Loaded 'xxx.dll') will be in output window when you execute `CoInitialize(NULL)`. and finally - if exception at this line - remove `CoInitializeEx` - this is not need - make sample not minimal and only confuse

Comment: so 1) you need only `CoInitialize(NULL);` line - remove all another lines after it 2)  *Clear all* in output window just before step over `CoInitialize(NULL);` 3.) what will be new in output window after this - paste it - *In the assembly there are only about 20 instructions before it and before those there are instructions with ?? ??* - paste this instructions - need look

Comment: and main - look list of loaded dlls (debug > windows > modules) - here exist module address, size, so you need detect by this or another tool - from which module this address or may be it not in any module at all

Comment: also add line `PVOID ThreadLocalStoragePointer = (PVOID)__readgsqword(0x58);` before call `CoInitialize(NULL);` - i almost sure that it will be not 0. but exception was (by your words just because it 0) - *rax and rcx beeing 0* but `mov  rax,qword ptr gs:[58h]` - `gs:[58h]` this is *ThreadLocalStoragePointer* and somebody damage it

Comment: Ok, i added the lines

Comment: You have Evil Code in your process that corrupts memory, subsequently causing the OS component to fail.  That more than one machine suffers from this problem is a good lead, along with what the debugger told you.  Uninstall/replace the Trend Micro malware.

Comment: strong suspicion of **TmUmEvt64.dll** - try uninstall it. the `25043370053` not located in any module and look like shellcode in executable memory. somebody damage the `ThreadLocalStoragePointer` which must not be zero. so begin from remove **TmUmEvt64.dll**

Comment: [*Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: TmUmEvt64.dll*](https://en.community.trendmicro.com/tm_en/topics/trendmicro-maximumsecurity-12-crash-the-microsoft-edge-on-my-system) - so this is really *TrendMicro MaximumSecurity*

Comment: Thank you very much, i think it is very possible that TrendMicro is causing the trouble... Unfortunaly the system admin is on vacation today and i can't kill it without the password. I will tell you if it worked without it tomorrow :)

Comment: After closing the antivirus software (TrendMicro) it works. Thanks guys